# how to dismiss progressDialog after completion of Async task

Tags: android, progressdialog

The method written below is used to show progressDialog(Just a spinner),

I had set setCancelable and setIndeterminate to false, Since i dont want the user to close this progressDailog.
What my problem is, I dont know how to close this progressDialog upoun completion of the AsyncTask.Please Help Me , I was googling for hours to solve the same, seen many Similar questions but none of these solved my problem!!

```
public class ListFriends extends ListActivity { 
         int intStat; 
         private static final int HOME = 0;
            private static final int ADD = 1;
            private static final int LOGOUT = 2;
            private static final int SETTINGS = 3;
            //private String friend;
            private String user;
            private String deviceUser;
            private String friendNameGlobal;
                        ....
                        ....

 public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
                    ........
                    ........
                    loadFromServer(user);
}
private void loadFromServer(String userReceived) {
        //buildToast("Please Wait while Updating The List");
        showProgress();
        String URL = "http://"+server+"/friendlistmob.php?userid="+userReceived;
         new DownloadXmlTask().execute(URL);
        }
  private class DownloadXmlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
                    .....
                    .....
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();//not working
 }
                   ....
                    ....

public void showProgress()
{
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);   
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait while updating List");        
progressDialog.show();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class ListFriends extends ListActivity { 
ProgressDialog pd;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pd= new ProgressDialog(ListActivity.this);
    pd.setTitle("Displaying dialog");  
    new DownloadXmlTask().execute();  
  }



class DownloadXmlTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
 {
      protected void onPreExecute()
      {           super.onPreExecute();
                //display progressdialog.
                 pd.show();
      } 

       protected void doInBackground(Void ...params)
      {  
            //http request. do not update ui here

            return null;
      } 

      //can also show progressupdate

       protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
      {     
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                //dismiss progressdialog.
                //update ui
                pd.dismiss(); 
      } 

   }
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Now i got a new error :Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method dismiss() from the type Dialog

Comment: i've posted the full structure above

Answer (score 2):

you will need to call `progressDialog.dismiss()` in `onPostExecute` to dismiss progressDialog as :

```
   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

           if (progressDialog !=null && progressDialog.isShowing())  
                progressDialog.dismiss(); //<<dismiss progressDialog here
            }
        }
```

Comment: +1. Just to add .. check if progress dialog is not null before checking for isShowing()...

Comment: When i added ProgressDialog.dismiss();
I got new error :Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method dismiss() from the type Dialog

Comment: @checkibig : use `progressDialog` instead of `ProgressDialog` for accessing dismiss() method. i mean use `ProgressDialog` class instance which u are using for showing progressdialog

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK But showProgress is only a method inside class   ListFriends which extends extends ListActivity .

Comment: @checkibig : plz add full class code if u are still not able to dismiss progressDialog . is u are running Asynctask in separate class ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK class details added

Comment: @checkibig : where u have declare progressDialog ? in ListFriends class ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK OMG ive missed it its with in the showProgress() method

Comment: @checki big remember to show progess dislog in onPreExecute() and dismiss it in onPostEecute();

Answer (score 0):

Dismiss, the dialog box in `onPostExecute` method.

```
             @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
               progressDialog.dismiss();

               // Update your UI.
                 }
```